# Calling putImageData from C++ wasm

Tags: javascript, c++, webassembly, emscripten

I have a `uint32` array in c++ wasm:

```
int size = width * height * dpr * dpr;
uint32_t *img = new uint32_t[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    img[i] = 0xFF0000FFu; // red (at least in js, not able to try it in c++)
}
```

I want to put it in a canvas, also using c++ wasm, how to write code?

```
thread_local const val document = val::global("document");
val canvas = document.call<val>("getElementById", val(canvasName));
val ctx = canvas.call<val>("getContext", val("2d"));
ctx.call<void>("putImageData", /* what to be put here ? */);
```

something equivalent in js would be

```
    const canvas = document.getElementById(canvasName)
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const img = new ImageData(width * dpr, height * dpr);
    const pixels = new Uint32Array(img.data.buffer);

    for (let i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        pixels[i] = 0xFF0000FF;
    }
    ctx.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
```

Since putImageData is using `Uint8ClampedArray`, I can of cource construct `img` with `uint8_t` if needed.

I have also tried to return the pointer and size to js, but copy from `module.HEAPU32` to `Uint8ClampedArray` is just too slow

Comment: so it turns out that i don't need to copy from `module.HEAPU32` to `Uint8ClampedArray`. 

in js, i can just do `let arr = new Uint8ClampedArray(module.HEAPU8.buffer, pointer, size * 4);` . 

idk if it count as answer my question, but i guess that'll solve my problem.